# Splitting string column with uppercase and lowercase string into two separate columns Pyspark/Python/Sql?

Tags: python, pyspark

**I have below Data in column Clicks:**

```
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-entertainment-audible
    MEM-BEN-LOC-MODAL-LOCATION-INPUT-Birmingham, AL, USA
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-entertainment-games
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-healthandwellness-love-and-meaning-after-50
    MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN-learn-more-aarp-travel-center-powered-by-expedia-10083
    MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN-learn-more-embassy-suites-by-hilton-1019
```

**I want to split the column Click into two columns Click_Upper and Click_lower**

Click_Upper (holds all uppercase characters)

```
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK
    MEM-BEN-LOC-MODAL-LOCATION-INPUT
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK
    MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK
    MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN
    MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN
```

**Click_lower (holds all lowercase characters)**

```
    entertainment-audible
    Birmingham, AL, USA
    entertainment-games
    healthandwellness-love-and-meaning-after-50
    learn-more-aarp-travel-center-powered-by-expedia-10083
    learn-more-embassy-suites-by-hilton-1019
```

I was trying to use split() function, but there are multiple delimiters (-) and the strings are of varying length so the code is not working for me. Also tried re but its breaking the string.

I would appreciate any guidance or help I could get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a regex statement to split the strings. You can use the re.group(x) method to access the two groups. Here is some more information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re

strings = ["MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-entertainment-audible",
    "MEM-BEN-LOC-MODAL-LOCATION-INPUT-Birmingham, AL, USA",
    "MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-entertainment-games",
    "MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-healthandwellness-love-and-meaning-after-50",
    "MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN-learn-more-aarp-travel-center-powered-by-expedia-10083",
    "MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN-learn-more-embassy-suites-by-hilton-1019"]

regex = "(?P<Click_Upper>[A-Z\-]+)-(?P<Click_Lower>.*)"

for string in strings:
    print(re.match(regex,string).groups())
```

Here is the output:

```
('MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK', 'entertainment-audible')
('MEM-BEN-LOC-MODAL-LOCATION-INPUT', 'Birmingham, AL, USA')
('MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK', 'entertainment-games')
('MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK', 'healthandwellness-love-and-meaning-after-50')
('MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN', 'learn-more-aarp-travel-center-powered-by-expedia-10083')
('MEM-BEN-BTN-LRN', 'learn-more-embassy-suites-by-hilton-1019')
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets `split` the `text` with `-`followed by `lower case` or `-`followed with `string Startingwithcaps but followed with lowercase letters`.

After split, we can slice `first element in list`, that will give us the `upper`

Once we have upper, `remove the upper` from whole text to remain with `lower`.

Code below and enjoy coding

Data

```
data=[
  (1,"MEM-BEN-BTN-CLK-healthandwellness-love-and-meaning-after-50"),
  (2,"MEM-BEN-LOC-MODAL-LOCATION-INPUT-Birmingham, AL, USA")
  ]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id','text'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Code

```
df.withColumn('upper', F.split('text','\\-(?=[a-z]+)|(\\-[A-Z][a-z]+)')[0]).withColumn("lower",expr("regexp_replace(text,upper,'')")).show(truncate=False)
```